# How do I describe a line (spline) in a file format

Tags: javascript, three.js

Anyone knows how to describe a line (spline) with either the .obj (Wavefront OBJ file format) or JSON Model format 3.1?

Comment: See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3465